# Java scanner adding variable conditions

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, conditional-statements

I'd like to ask how do i exactly condition what my program does if my user types in a character or a string if i want him to type an integer instead? I tried to do it how i showed here in quotes and also tried with "equals". The second method didn't work the first seems to be behaving strangely the IF part works but ELSE is completely ignored.

```
  public static void main(String[] args){

Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter first integer: ");

int number1 = input.nextInt();// prompt
    if (number1 == (char)number1){

    System.out.println("Ok.");
    }
    else{  
     System.out.println("You were supposed to type in an int..");
     System.exit(1);
    }

System.out.print("Enter second integer: ");
int number2 = input.nextInt();// prompt
int sum =(number1 + number2);

System.out.printf("Your sum is: %d%n", sum);

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use the regular expression in the hasNext() function as follows to have a finer control, for example use the following pattern if you look for the numbers,

```
sc.hasNext("[0-9]+")
```

Here is the documentation for the hasNext(String pattern) function,

> public boolean hasNext(Pattern pattern)
>
> Returns true if the next complete token matches the specified pattern. A complete token is prefixed and postfixed by input that matches the delimiter pattern. This method may block while waiting for input. The scanner does not advance past any input.

Here is the simple code to perform the check,

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
int input = 0;
while(true) {
    System.out.println("enter a number");
    if(sc.hasNext("[0-9]+")) {
        input = sc.nextInt();
        break;
    } else {
        System.out.println("not a number, try again");
        sc.next(); // just consume, but ignore as its not a number
    }
}
System.out.println("Entered number is : "+input);
```

Comment: can you try this solution and let me know?

Comment: i just tried it but when i start program and type an int program just skips to the next line and seems to stop working and if i type a character or anything other than a number it throws out same error as it did before.

Comment: Does it work? Can you try the updated one? which goes back and asks for the input if the entered value is in incorrect format.

Comment: on a side note, can i somehow set the numbers higher in this method? other than 0-9?

Comment: Yes, use the following to input any number      sc.hasNext("[0-9]+") .. I'm editing the result also with the same. But if you want to have some finer control on the digits and etc, refer this link - http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use a user defined function as shown below and call it

```
public static boolean isNum(String input)  
{  
  try  
  {  
    int d = Integer.parseInt(input);  
  }  
  catch(NumberFormatException e)  
  {  
    return false;  
  }  
  return true;  
}
```

Then you can call this method from your main function.

```
if(isNum(number1))
```

Comment: Very incorrect answer...Scanner.nextInt() will always return int or program will halt. Why suggesting additional validation.

Answer (score 0):

Scanner.nextInt(); Scans the next token of the input as an int.
Program won't execute beyond this line if input is not int.

So it will never enter else part. Don't do any int validation.

I would suggest always use try/catch block to handle incorrect input and show useful message. Also don't forget to close Scanner object.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question, but I see this as follows:

Users will always type a sequence of characters from the input, then your program has to check if that String can be converted to Int, if it can not be converted it should prompt back to the user telling the typed data is not an int. In that case your nextInt will throw an InputMismatchException.

Probably a much more elegant solution is to use hasNextInt(10):
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter first integer: ");

```
    if (input.hasNextInt(10)){
        System.out.println("Ok. Typed number: " + input.nextInt());
    }else{  
        System.out.println("You were supposed to type in an int..");
        System.exit(1);
    }
[...]
}
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work either - what i want is this : I want user to type in an integer; if user types ANYTHING else than integer i want to display an error message and possibly move one step behind so he can type again until he writes an int.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
        try {
            int number1 = sc.nextInt();// prompt
            System.out.println("Ok.");
        } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
            System.out.println("You were supposed to type in an int..");
            System.exit(1);
        }
```

Comment: I tried to but it says: "variable number 1 is not used" and it doesnt sum up too